# Different callback function for a topic with different namespaces?

Tags: ros, namespace, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I have several move_base nodes launched each in a separate namespace. Now I have a list of robot objects as well. When I subscribe to a topic from namespace robot_1, I would like the callback function to be called that corresponds to robot_1 object in the list of robot objects. As of now I simply subscribe to the callbacks with different names. For ex:
in the robot_1 instance I have a subscriber for /robot_1/topic_name
while in the robot_2 instance I have /robot_2/topic_name
These subscribers are merely functions within the robot class.
Any idea how I could link the subscriber callback to the particular object instance? Really appreciate the help!
Thank you

EDIT: Just an overview of my program.
I have a derived class "robot", which is derived from a base class "agent". Now the process "trader" has a list of robots that are initialized. Each robot publishes an

odom to topic /robot_x/odom where x=robot_number.

Now in the "robot" constructor I initialize a NodeHandle in namespace robot_x

```
ros::NodeHandle nhr(robot_number);
```

And then I subscribe to the corresponding "odom" in a member function.

```
odom_sub = nhr.subscribe("odom", 100, &robot::odom_callback, this);
```

This works perfectly and I get the odometry for the n robots. However:

```
void robot::odom_callback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg){
cout<<"robot_number"<<endl; /* Getting garbage values */
//robot_number is a variable in the base class agent
}
```

Please let me know if I should clarify more. Really appreciate the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48794/different-callback-function-for-a-topic-with-different-namespaces?/) by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2012-11-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-23**:
Please do not re-type code but copy-paste it as stated in the [support guidelines](http://ros.org/wiki/Support). The cout line above will definitely not print garbage values. It will just print the string `robot_number`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What do you mean with objects? Nodes?

In that case, just subscribe to topic_name in the node and when you launch the node put it in a namespace like robot_1/2... This will automatically remap the topics.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on 2012-11-22**:
So they are not different nodes. They are merely a list of class instances. I have a class called "robot" and there are n robot objects. Each robot object must listen to the topic in its corresponding namespace. Does that clarify a bit?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-22**:
That is also simple. Just pass in the name (e.g. robot_2) to your robot object and make it subscribe to the topic that you construct from that name.

**Comment by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on 2012-11-22**:
Thats what I did and it does not quite work. During the callback it is unable to access values of other attributes  encapsulated in that object. It gets garbage values for the other member variables. I am guessing the callback is happening on a new instance of the class rather than the member func.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-22**:
That is not possible. Callbacks don't construct objects. You'll need to show a minimal example of your code to get some more precise help.